# replace("\n", "") is not working

Tags: java, string, replace

```
String in = "dr. goldberg offers everything i look for in a general practitioner.  he's nice and easy to talk to without being patronizing; he's always on time in seeing his patients; he's affiliated with a top-notch hospital (nyu) which my parents have explained to me is very important in case something happens and you need surgery; and you can get referrals to see specialists without having to see him first.  really, what more do you need?  i'm sitting here trying to think of any complaint\n\ns i have about him, but i'm really drawing\n a blank.";
```

This code seems to be working perfectly fine.

```
in = in.replaceAll("\n", "");
```

but this

```
for(String temp: review){
    String reviews = (StringUtils.substringBetween(temp,"\"text\": \"", "\", \"type\"")).replaceAll("\n", "");

    if(reviews.equals(in)){
        System.out.println("yes");
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

does not seem to work. It is not removing new line constant, Can someone please explain why!

(I am using substringBetween to get a part of text from a file)

Comment: what does `StringUtils.substringBetween(temp,"\"text\": \"", "\", \"type\""))` evalutes to at runtime ?

Comment: @JigarJoshi - it evaluates to the same string asinput2 but with new line constant, the replace doesn't seem to be working

Comment: also i am checking equality of these two strings, using input.equals(reviews), it should evaluate to true, but it is not.

Comment: also note that you are using `replace()` not `replaceAll()` so it won't replace all but first

Comment: @RuslanOstafiychuk - i have tried that and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @JigarJoshi - tried that also, still no luck. if i use replace("\\n",""); it replaces the new line constant but input.equals(reviews) doesnt evaluate to true.

Comment: can you post reproducible code ?

Comment: would you mind editing it in question to make it readable ?

Comment: @JigarJoshi - done that,please let me know if you can find some solution

Comment: again this code is not reproducible, just `-A 5 -B 4` of main code, can you create a simple main class and reproduce it ?

Comment: that is the problem here, if i directly write the sentence myself and heck for equality, it seems to be working, but when i am extracting the same sentence from the file and trying to remove new line constant it is not working@JigarJoshi

Comment: @shreyaseshu Have you considered the possibility that the line terminator is `\r\n`, not just `\n`?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following code:

```
String sample="This string has new line \\n " + "New line is here if \\n \n is working";
    System.out.println("Original String: " + sample); //replacing \n or newline character so that all text come in one line 
    System.out.println("Escaped String: " + sample.replaceAll("\n", ""));
```

Alternatively, you can use system properties to remove new line character as shown below:

```
String text = readFileAsString("words.txt"); 
text = text.replace(System.getProperty("line.separator"), "");
```